# Not able to interact with map view inside CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, floating-action-button, android-coordinatorlayout

I am trying to add FAB's,MapView,toolbar and DrawerLayout inside the CoordinatorLayout. My map-view will cover the whole screen and FAB's will be placed over the map-view. I've achieved everything but the problem is with the map-view. I'm not able to interact with it. Also when I open the drawer, it is getting below the FAB's and user's can interact with it which I don't want.

Following is my xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            tools:showIn="@layout/activity_map_view">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_items" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fab_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab3"
        style="@style/floating_action_button"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        app:fabSize="mini" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        style="@style/floating_action_button"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/fab3"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_week"
        app:fabSize="mini" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab1"
        style="@style/floating_action_button"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/fab2"
        android:src="@drawable/cast_ic_notification_1"
        app:fabSize="mini" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        style="@style/floating_action_button"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/fab1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plusone_medium_off_client"
        app:backgroundTint="#00FF00"
        app:fabSize="normal" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also when I set visibility of DrawerLayout to 'gone', I can interact with map which indicates that my DrawerLayout is above the map-view and I'm not able to get rid of it.

Any issues with my XML ? Attached are the screenshot when my drawer is open and closed . [image: I want FAB below the drawer menu so that user can not interact with it.]
[image: I can not interact with the map]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how it should look (maybe one from a pre-lollipop device). Also, I doubt you would want to have the mapView in the appbar, since the appbar is usually used for things like Toolbars and TabLayouts.

Comment: @G.deWit Thanks for your comment. removed map-view from AppBarLayout and it is working fine for all the devices.

Comment: @G.deWit But now my navigationBar is not visible on pre-lollipop devices.

Comment: can you update your xml to how it is now. Is it the only thing you changed?

Comment: @G.deWit updated the XML. My App Bar is visible now.

Comment: Appbar or NavigationBar, I'm a bit confused. So is everything working now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93142/discussion-between-amrut-and-g-dewit).

Comment: Did you find a solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior", because this is for the content scroll but your view it's filling the view so it's not scrollable only the map it's scrollable but that it's the mapView who handle it not the coordinatorLayout.